# Route53 not resolving domain name to an ec2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-route53

Elastic IP associated with an EC2 instance

[image]

I had made a transfer of domain name from one aws account to a another, the domain name worked with my previous account and it resolved to an S3 bucket before but after the transfer to an new account it does not resolve the connection to EC2 instance. I'm trying to host a website with the domain name ketan.io. Please help and also educate me if I need to open any port in the firewall other than the HTTP and HTTPS for the DNS to resolve to the EC2 instance. I have added the ServerName as ketan.io in apache config file and also added the domain with the elastic IP address in the /etc/hosts file. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The link given above is an image of the aws route53 record set screen.

Answer (score 3):

Your domain ketan.io isn't associated with Hosted Zone Name Servers: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/ketan.io - this should display what appears as NS record in your Hosted Zone. For example: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/evgenyg.io (but don't copy my name servers, your Hosted Zone has a different list)

Your Name Servers listed as NS record in your screenshot: ns-849.awsdns-42.net, ns-90.awsdns-11.com, ns-1303.awsdns-34.org, ns-1655.awsdns-14.co.uk.

Once you have 4 Name Servers you need to follow these instructions to update your domain: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html

This will "connect" ketan.io with Route 53 DNS servers.

Comment: I had done the name server part and the Dig displays the new name servers but I'm still facing issues. The web browser says "the web page not available ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". I created a new hosted zone, added the elastic IP record to the dns server.[ edited the ns as instructed in the register domain panel and also got an email confirmation].

Comment: According to 'dig' the A-IPv4 records are not associated but according to my aws Elastic IP and Route53 it is. I don't know why, any suggestions?

Comment: ketan.io now resolves as 52.37.236.81: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/ketan.io - is that what you intended to do?

Comment: Your A record in the Hosted Zone for ketan.io should be an EIP you've assigned to your EC2 instance.

Comment: You might experience DNS caching issue, I was able to resolve your domain directly from Google DNS on one of the dev boxes: dig +short ketan.io @8.8.8.8. Then I was able to curl http://ketan.io. But from my laptop I still can't resolve this domain. Try specifying 8.8.8.8 as your DNS resolver.